# extjs grid real full afterrender event?

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, grid

i am having extjs GridPanel

when i load store:

```
I do Ext.getBody().mask();

Grid 'afterrender' event fires first

Store 'load' event fires second

I attached unmask function to  store load 'event'
```

but there are few moments after that event, 
when i see white grid (between unmask and  rows populating).

what is the proper way to unmask on real full afterrender event?
i mean - when all rows are rendered.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to suggest the gridview's `loadMask` config as covered [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-cfg-loadMask) in the docs. But I noticed that it wasn't working for me for some reason.

If it doesn't work for you either, just use the gridview's `refresh` event as covered [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-event-refresh). It will only fire after the data is fully loaded into the grid. You can attach it through your gridpanel's `viewConfig` config like so:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'My Grid Panel',
    // ... other grid panel configs
    viewConfig: {
        listeners: {
            refresh: function(gridview) {
                console.log(gridview);
                console.log('is fully loaded');
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Or if you are using MVC app architecture:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    models: ['MyModel'],

    stores: ['MyStore'],

    views:  ['MyGridPanel'],

    init: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.control({

            // ... other event handlers

            'mygridpanel > gridview': {

                refresh: function(gridview) {
                    console.log(gridview);
                    console.log('is fully loaded');
                }

            },
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: a bit late, but i've just had to struggle with a similar issue. in Extjs 3.4 I could work with the grid event `viewready`.